# trouble with storage with prompt

Tags: javascript

i need when i click on input then must prompt and result transferred to storage, help me please, i tried to find this resolve in google but no use:(

```
const output = document.querySelector('[data-output]');

const LOCAL_STORAGE_LIST_KEY = 'task.lists';
const LOCAL_STORAGE_SELECTED_LIST_ID_KEY = 'task.selectedListId';
let lists = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_LIST_KEY)) || [];
let selectedListId = localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_SELECTED_LIST_ID_KEY);

output.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let txt = prompt('Enter what you want to do ^^').toString();
    lists.push(txt);
    saveAndRender();
});
```

Comment: `.toString()` - It's a method, not a property, so you need the brackets

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gure8y6v/

Comment: In your renderLists function you are using list.name but your items in lists are string. So when you are pushing txt in lists you need to insert as object

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to be in the renderLists function, which is on the JSFiddle that you linked in the comments. You're looping over your `lists` Array, which contains the input String - But you're trying to access properties as if it was an Object; which is instead giving you `undefined`

You have `createList`which will turn that input into an Object with the current keys, so I assume you meant to include that

```js
output.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let txt = prompt('Enter what you want to do ^^').toString();
    lists.push(createList(txt));
    saveAndRender();
});
```

[Here is an updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2mu5sz3/)